# Matching several patterns on one line

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I often use a program called `tty0tty`, which creates a null modem using PTYs. Now I want to make it part of an automated process.

When I start `tty0tty` it prints

```
(/dev/pts/1) <=> (/dev/pts/2)
```

Would it be possible to parse the output and use the matches as parameters to another program? So that the following lines could be automated:

```
linux$ tty0tty &
(/dev/pts/X) <=> (/dev/pts/Y)
linux$ someprogram /dev/pts/X &
linux$ microcom /dev/pts/Y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` and [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
read left right < <(tty0tty | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/[()<=>]//g' &)
```

After that, `$left` is `/dev/pts/X` and `right` is `/dev/pts/Y`.

This cheats a little - we just replace the characters `(`, `)`, `<`, `=`, and `>` with nothing, and then rely on the shell's word splitting after that.

We pipe the `tty0tty` output into `head` so we only take the first (only) line of output and don't block forever. From there it goes into the `sed` command that does the replacement, then use the shell's `read` bultin to bind the shell variables `left` and `right` to the first and second words of the input we give it. We get that input from the `<(...)`. `<(...)` runs `...` in a subshell and connects its output to a pipe we can read from. We feed that pipe into `read` with the first `<`, so it gets `/dev/pts/X  /dev/pts/Y` and splits it into the two words we wanted.

After this you could run `someprogram $left` and `microcom $right` as desired.

Comment: Neat trick :-). Seems to be almost working. Only problem seems to be that tty0tty have to keep running, that is why I started it as `tty0tty &`. Seems like `sed` keeps waiting for more input.

Comment: You can put the `&` inside the subshell (after the `sed` command). To make `sed` stop, pipe to `head -n 1` in between (now edited in). It's a hack, but it is effective.

Comment: I think that `head` is running into the same problem as `sed`. Running `tty0tty | head -n 1` doesn't give any output. Tried to add the 'unbuffered' flag to sed, but that did not seem to help. Using `unbuffer` command made it work though. The hackiness is now over 9000 ;).

The line I finally used is `read left right < <(unbuffer tty0tty | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/[()<=>]//g' &)`